# How to write text in a cell from top to bottom in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I'd like to write text in a cell from top to bottom just like the vertical text orientation in EXCEL using openpyxl packages in python.
But I can't do that.
Could anyone please help me?
[I uploaded the exact image I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtwOq.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `alignment` attribute of a cell and set the `textRotation` to the needed angle (1-180). You can read more abot it in the openpyxl documentation - [Here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.alignment.html#openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment.textRotation).

Code Example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['A1'] = 'Example'
ws['A1'].alignment = Alignment(textRotation=180)

wb.save('Example.xlsx')
```

Output:

[image: rotated text in Excel]

If you want the charecters to be written horizontally but the word verticaly just set `textRotation` to `255`:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['A1'] = 'Hello'
ws['A1'].alignment = Alignment(textRotation=255)

wb.save('Example.xlsx')
```

Output:

[image: Text Rotation 2]

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I want to print "15日", It prints like "1 \n 5 \n 日", but I want it to print like "15 \n 日". How could I do that?

Comment: @Metalgear So just write it as a regular string with `\n`... like `"15 \n 日"`